Multi producer multi consumer ring buffer implementation using disruptor pattern
I was trying to implement disruptor pattern of multi-producer and multi-consumer ring buffer whose implementation are described here (for consumer) and here (for producer). I am observing inconsistency in consumers where 1 consumer is losing some data and others have all the data.
Below is my implementation-
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex io_mutex;

template <typename T>
T generate_random_element()
{
    return {};
}
template <>
std::string generate_random_element()
{
    int i = std::rand();
    return std::to_string(i);
}

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
class RingBuffer
{
public:
    std::vector<T> m_buffer;
    std::atomic_int cursor;
    RingBuffer() : m_buffer(SIZE), cursor(-1) {}

    int get_cursor() const
    {
        return cursor;
    }

    T &get_element(size_t id)
    {
        return m_buffer[id % SIZE];
    }

    const T &get_element(size_t id) const
    {
        return m_buffer[id % SIZE];
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
class Consumer
{
    using RingBuf = RingBuffer<T, SIZE>;
    const RingBuf &m_ring_buffer;
    size_t next_expected_seq_no;
    int id;
    std::atomic_bool consume;
    std::vector<T> m_consumed_items;

public:

    Consumer(const RingBuf &ring_buffer, int id) : m_ring_buffer(ring_buffer), id(id), consume(true), next_expected_seq_no(0) {}

    size_t get_next_expected_seq() const
    {
        return next_expected_seq_no;
    }

    void consume_objects()
    {
        while (consume)
        {
            while ((m_ring_buffer.cursor < next_expected_seq_no) && consume)
                ;
            while (next_expected_seq_no <= m_ring_buffer.cursor)
            {
                m_consumed_items.push_back(m_ring_buffer.get_element(next_expected_seq_no++));
            }
        }
    }

    void stop()
    {
        consume = false;
    }

    Consumer(Consumer &&other) = default;
    Consumer &operator=(Consumer &&other) = default;
    Consumer(const Consumer &other) : m_ring_buffer(other.m_ring_buffer)
    {
        id = other.id;
        next_expected_seq_no = other.next_expected_seq_no;
        consume = other.consume.load();
        m_consumed_items = other.m_consumed_items;
    }
    Consumer() = default;

    ~Consumer()
    {
        stop();
        std::scoped_lock sl(io_mutex);
        std::cout << "Consumer: " << id;
        for (const auto &v : m_consumed_items)
            std::cout << "\t" << v;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
class ProducerBarrier
{
    std::vector<Consumer<T, SIZE>> &consumers;
    std::atomic<size_t> id_to_allocate;
    std::atomic<size_t> min_consumer_seq_no;

public:
    RingBuffer<T, SIZE> &m_ring_buffer;
    ProducerBarrier(RingBuffer<T, SIZE> &ring_buffer, std::vector<Consumer<T, SIZE>> &consumers) : m_ring_buffer(ring_buffer), consumers(consumers), min_consumer_seq_no(0), id_to_allocate(0)
    {
    }

    void get_min_consumer_seq_no()
    {
        size_t minval = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
        for (const auto &consumer : consumers)
            minval = std::min(minval, consumer.get_next_expected_seq());
        min_consumer_seq_no = minval;
    }

    size_t get_next_id()
    {
        size_t slowest_consumer_id = min_consumer_seq_no.load();
        slowest_consumer_id += SIZE;
        while (slowest_consumer_id == id_to_allocate)
        {
            get_min_consumer_seq_no();
            slowest_consumer_id = min_consumer_seq_no.load();
            slowest_consumer_id += SIZE;
        }
        return id_to_allocate++;
    }

    void commit(size_t id)
    {
        id--;
        while (m_ring_buffer.cursor != id)
            ;
        m_ring_buffer.cursor++;
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
class Producer
{
    ProducerBarrier<T, SIZE> &m_producer_barrier;
    std::vector<T> m_produced_items;
    int id;
    int items_to_produce;

public:
    Producer(ProducerBarrier<T, SIZE> &producer_barrier, int id, int items_to_produce) : m_producer_barrier(producer_barrier), id(id), items_to_produce(items_to_produce) {}

    void produce()
    {
        while (items_to_produce-- > 0)
        {
            auto item = generate_random_element<std::string>();
            size_t item_id = m_producer_barrier.get_next_id(), id_in_buffer = item_id % SIZE;
            m_producer_barrier.m_ring_buffer.m_buffer[id_in_buffer] = item;
            m_produced_items.emplace_back(item);

            m_producer_barrier.commit(item_id);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    using dataT = std::string;
    static constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 4;
    static constexpr size_t PRODUCER_CNT = 12;
    static constexpr size_t ITEMS_TO_PRODUCE = 5;
    static constexpr size_t CONSUMER_CNT = 5;

    RingBuffer<dataT, BUFFER_SIZE> buf;
    std::vector<Consumer<dataT, BUFFER_SIZE>> consumers; // TODO: pre_allocate with CONSUMER_CNT
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMER_CNT; i++)
    {
        consumers.emplace_back(buf, i);
    }
    ProducerBarrier<dataT, BUFFER_SIZE> barrier(buf, consumers);
    std::vector<Producer<dataT, BUFFER_SIZE>> producers; // TODO: pre_allocate with PRODUCER_CNT
    for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_CNT; i++)
    {
        producers.emplace_back(barrier, i, ITEMS_TO_PRODUCE);
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> threads_list;
    for (auto &producer : producers)
    {
        threads_list.emplace_back(std::thread(&Producer<dataT, BUFFER_SIZE>::produce, &producer));
    }
    for (auto &consumer : consumers)
    {
        threads_list.emplace_back(std::thread(&Consumer<dataT, BUFFER_SIZE>::consume_objects, &consumer));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_CNT; i++)
    {
        threads_list[i].join();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMER_CNT; i++)
    {
        consumers[i].stop();
        threads_list[i + PRODUCER_CNT].join();
    }

    return 0;
}

Essentially, the ProducerBarrier maintains id_to_allocate which is the next empty index into the ring buffer and each Consumer object stores their separate sequence number in next_expected_seq_no. RingBuffer maintains a cursor variable which shows what is the latest value available to be read, this value is updated by different producers via the single ProducerBarrier instance.
I printed the results of consumption of each variable in their destructor expecting them to exactly match having count PRODUCER_CNT * ITEMS_TO_PRODUCE. But the output of the consumers are not matching, particularly after index 0, 16, 32..
Consumer: 4     16807   **16531729**        **1817129560**      **1264817709**      **1441282327**      **1131570933**      101027544       1457850878      1458777923      2007237709  823564440       1115438165      1784484492      74243042        114807987       1137522503      1474833169      **16531729**        1817129560      1264817709  1441282327      1131570933      197493099       1404280278      893351816       1505795335      1636807826      563613512       1954899097      101929267   1580723810      704877633       1646035001      1025921153      1624379149      784558821       530511967       2110010672      1551901393      1617819336  1998097157      1399125485      156091745       896544303       1356425228      1899894091      585640194       937186357       1646035001      1025921153  143542612       510616708       590357944       771515668       357571490       823378840       1044788124      1927702196      1952509530      130060903
Consumer: 3     16807   282475249       1622650073      984943658       1144108930      470211272       101027544       1457850878      1458777923      2007237709  823564440       1115438165      1784484492      74243042        114807987       1137522503      **1358580979**      **2128236579**      1624379149      784558821   530511967       2110010672      1551901393      1617819336      893351816       1505795335      1636807826      563613512       1954899097      101929267   1580723810      704877633       1646035001      1025921153      1624379149      784558821       530511967       2110010672      1551901393      1617819336  1998097157      1399125485      156091745       896544303       1356425228      1899894091      585640194       937186357       1646035001      1025921153  143542612       510616708       590357944       771515668       357571490       823378840       1044788124      1927702196      1952509530      130060903
Consumer: 2     16807   282475249       1622650073      984943658       1144108930      470211272       101027544       1457850878      1458777923      2007237709  823564440       1115438165      1784484492      74243042        114807987       1137522503      1646035001      1025921153      1624379149      784558821   530511967       2110010672      1551901393      1617819336      1998097157      1399125485      156091745       896544303       1356425228      1899894091  585640194       937186357       1646035001      1025921153      1624379149      784558821       530511967       2110010672      1551901393      1617819336  1998097157      1399125485      156091745       896544303       1356425228      1899894091      585640194       937186357       1646035001      1025921153  143542612       510616708       590357944       771515668       357571490       823378840       1044788124      1927702196      1952509530      130060903
Consumer: 1     16807   282475249       1622650073      984943658       1144108930      470211272       101027544       1457850878      1458777923      2007237709  823564440       1115438165      1784484492      74243042        114807987       1137522503      1474833169      16531729        1817129560      1264817709  1441282327      1131570933      197493099       1404280278      893351816       1505795335      1636807826      563613512       1954899097      101929267   1580723810      704877633       1358580979      2128236579      1624379149      784558821       530511967       2110010672      1551901393      1617819336  1998097157      1399125485      156091745       896544303       1356425228      1899894091      585640194       937186357       1646035001      1025921153  143542612       510616708       590357944       771515668       357571490       823378840       1044788124      1927702196      1952509530      130060903
Consumer: 0     16807   282475249       1622650073      984943658       1144108930      470211272       101027544       1457850878      1458777923      2007237709  823564440       1115438165      1784484492      74243042        114807987       1137522503      1474833169      16531729        1817129560      1264817709  1441282327      1131570933      197493099       1404280278      893351816       1505795335      1636807826      563613512       1954899097      101929267   1580723810      704877633       1646035001      1025921153      1624379149      784558821       530511967       2110010672      1551901393      1617819336  1998097157      1399125485      156091745       896544303       1356425228      1899894091      585640194       937186357       1646035001      1025921153  143542612       510616708       590357944       771515668       357571490       823378840       1044788124      1927702196      1952509530      130060903

Problem seems to be in function get_next_id() which I think is not handling the buffer full case very well, but I am not able to debug the exact reason.

I'm honestly not sure why you expect a particular distribution of tasks among the consumers. Multithreading is inherently unreliable in that area and unless you specifically sync something, you can't rely on it. Your code is also sometimes hard to follow. For example, there are getters for some members, but they are also public and accessed directly. Another example is that sometimes you use int id, sometimes size_t id, without clarifying what type of ID those are and what they identify. I could imagine you mixed up some things, too. In any case, consider codereview.stackexchange.com!

No @Ulrich, please don't recommend [codereview.se] for code that's not producing expected results: broken code is not ready for review until it's fixed.

I think the author is capable of looking at it and making an informed decision, @TobySpeight. Note that I wrote "consider", which is exactly that. I'm not arguing that the code needs work correctly first, though I'm not sure if the code or the expectations are the problem yet.

Unfortunately, many askers don't make informed decisions, but see such a suggestion as a recommendation to post the exact same question, which gives them a bad experience.  That's exactly what happened in this case.  It's worth being more explicit when you mention [codereview.se] that it's for improving code that already works to the author's satisfaction, to help avoid frustrating new askers.  I know it wasn't your intent to encourage off-topic posting, but that turned out to be the effect this time.  :(

Have you looked at other disruptor implementations?  E.g. https://github.com/Abc-Arbitrage/Disruptor-cpp
